# Check if property can be lazy loaded/is available without having to catch an exception

Tags: c#, .net, database, visual-studio, entity-framework

Basically I want to enable my foreign key properties to be loaded when needed even though the original context has been disposed.

I thought about editing the properties getters:

```
if (Author==null)
{
    //load the author userprofile in a new dbcontext
    Author = loadedAuthor;
}
return Author;
```

(Author is a foreign key property in the entity).

However every time I even attempt to check if the property is null it throws the following exception:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

Is there no way to check if the property is "locally available" without having to catch an exception?

Comment: It looks like your dbcontext has already been disposed.. can you post how you're getting loadedAuthor?

Comment: @dumass
I would get loadedAuthor by using a new dbcontext.
The issue is how to check if it's loaded so I would know if I should get it using a new dbcontext or just pick it from the instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called `AuthorReference` that has a `IsLoaded` property. You can use that to check if your `Author` reference is loaded.

Comment: How exactly do I check it? Could you give an example? I don't see AuthorReference anywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, this solution only works for EF4, but not the newer `DbContext`. I did not read your question correctly. As far as I know there is no way to check if a reference is loaded once the context is disposed.